# Need to prove that the solution for a PDE problem is odd

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations

So I have the following problem

$$ \begin{cases} \Delta u(x,y)=4\arctan(x),  && \text{if } (x,y) \in B(0,2) \\ u(x,y)=0, && \text{if } (x,y) \in \partial B(0,2) \end{cases} $$

1. I need to show that the solution is odd in $x$. That's $\space$$u(-x,y)=-u(x,y)$. Can I assume that $u(x,y)$ is even in $x$ and find a contradiction?
2. Also, I managed to show that $|u(x,y)|\le2\pi$ , but how am I supposed to find a better aproximation than $2\pi$?

Answer (score 2):

Let $u(x,y)$ a solution. Let $x'=-x$ and then
$$ \Delta [-u(-x,y)]=-(\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2})u(-x,y)=-(\frac{\partial^2}{\partial (x')^2}+\frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2})u(x',y)=-4\arctan(x')=\arctan(x) $$
So $-u(-x,y)$ is a solution. By the uniqueness of the solution of the equation, one has $-u(-x,y)=u(x,y)$ or $u(-x,y)=-u(x,y)$.